# VSTO Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, outlook

I have some trouble about VSTO in the new Outlook 2013. In the past we had some VBS-Script which expands all MAPI-Folder (including public folders!). Now this script isn't working any more so I tried to use VSTO to handle this basically simple thing. For testing reasons a simple safe example how to select a folder:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = this.Application.Session.PickFolder();
this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = folder ;
this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder.Display();
```

Go and try to run this code on Outlook 2007 to Outlook 2010 and it will run. If you try this on Outlook 2013 you will see a blank inbox. If you try to select something in there you will see the messages are there in the back but you can't see them. I am very sure this is a huge (annoying) MS-Office 2013 Bug - Could some of you agree?

Comment: This isn't likely a bug more of an overal behavior change.  We can't use this code because it won't compile.

Comment: Mh strange - did you installed the last VSTO for VS2012?

Comment: The reason your code won't compile is because your code uses a Session variable.